# Remove the reversing pairs

Tags: java, string, replace

I would like to ask question which I thought it was simple. 
However, it might be not at least to me.

Here are lots of string pairs. 
My question would be how to remove the reversing pairs. It's because the (A-B) and (B-A) are the same to me. I would like to keep only one.

```
Input:
A    B
A    C
A    D
B    A
C    A
D    A
B    D
D    B

Expect output
A    B
A    C
A    D
B    D
```

I try `ArrayListMultimap` to get (key, List) pairs.

```
(A, B; C; D)
(B, A; D)
....
```

However, I still have `(A,B)` and `(B,A)`
Any comments are welcome. Thank you.

Comment: Probably there are many ways. You should show your code.

Comment: what is the datastructure

Comment: Try somethink and come back if you have Problems with it

Answer (score 0):

Create a List of strings, which will contain "AB", "BC", etc..

```
List<String> = new ArrayList<String>() strings;
```

Here, you should loop on your left and right strings, concatenate and populate the List, avoiding what you consider as duplicates :

```
for(<your loop condition here, to iterate over left and right strings>) {

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append(leftString); // say "A"
sb.append(rightString); // say "B"

// now sb contains "AB"

// We only append the String if the reverse doesn't already exists in the List
if(!strings.contains(sb.reverse().toString()))   // reverse yields "BA"
  strings.add(sb.toString());

}
```

You're done, you have a list of strings without duplicates.

If you want to retrieve left and right parts, just use `substring(0,1)` and `substring (1,2)`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I figured this out. Here is the code

```
    Scanner pairs = new Scanner(new File("TestSet.txt"));
    ArrayListMultimap<String,String> dataset = ArrayListMultimap.create();   
        while (pairs.hasNextLine()){
        String data0 = pairs.nextLine();
        String [] array0 = data0.split("\t", 3);
        String itemA = array0[0];
        String itemB = array0[1];
            if(dataset.containsKey(itemB) && dataset.containsEntry(itemB, itemA)){
            }
            else{
              dataset.put(itemA, itemB);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach (more instructive I think) is to consider a pair of string as the following class:

```
class StringPair{
String s1,s2;
public StringPair(String _s1, String _s2) {
    this.s1=_s1;
    this.s2=_s2;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object other) {
    if (other == null) return false;
    if (other == this) return true;
    if (!(other instanceof StringPair))return false;
    StringPair p = (StringPair)other;
    return (s1.equals(p.s1) && s2.equals(p.s2))
            || ( s1.equals(p.s2) && s2.equals(p.s1));
}


@Override
public int hashCode() {
    String s;
    if(s1.compareTo(s2) <= 0)
        s=s1+s2;
    else
        s=s2+s1;
    return s.hashCode();
}
```

}

and then use a SET implementation to store the ALL String pairs (this will take care of removing the duplicates). Set does not allows to contain duplicates.

***Quoting the javadoc:***

> Adds the specified element to this set if it is not already present (optional operation). More formally, adds the specified element e to this set if the set contains no element e2 such that (e==null ? e2==null : e.equals(e2)). If this set already contains the element, the call leaves the set unchanged and returns false. In combination with the restriction on constructors, this ensures that sets never contain duplicate elements.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashSet<StringPair> pairs = new HashSet<StringPair>();
    pairs.add(new StringPair("A", "B"));
    pairs.add(new StringPair("B", "A"));
    pairs.add(new StringPair("B", "C"));
    pairs.add(new StringPair("B", "C"));
    pairs.add(new StringPair("B", "B"));

    for (Iterator<StringPair> i = pairs.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
        StringPair stringPair = (StringPair) i.next();
        System.out.println(stringPair.s1+" "+stringPair.s2);
    }
}
```

which outputs:

> ```
> B B
> A B
> B C
> ```